# Mergesort on the right and left error

Tags: arrays, sorting, mergesort

```
import random
arr = random.sample(xrange(1,200001), 200000)
print (arr)

def mergesort(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr

    m = len(arr) / 2
    l = mergesort(arr[:m])
    r = mergesort(arr[m:])

    if not len(l) or not len(r) or len(0):
        return l or r
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    while (len(result) < len(r)+len(l)):
        if l[i] < r[j]:
            result.append(l[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(r[j])
            j += 1
            if i == len(l) or j == len(r):
                result.extend(l[i:] or r[j:])
                break

        return result
mergesort(arr)
```

So I have the error for splitting this program. I am trying to generate numbers 1-200,000 randomly out of order and display them all. Then I am trying to merge sort them into 2 separate files and then one to one file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (zero experience in programming)

Comment: Please provide more details as to what the problem is that you are having.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The if i == len(l) ... appears to be indented incorrectly. You could have two ifs, just after i += 1, if i == len(l): / result.extend(r[j:]) / break and just after j += 1, if j == len(r): / result.extend(l[i:]) / break .